# splitting a tuple to use values as filter in sql query

Tags: python, python-2.7

I had a large list of IDs and would like to use it as a filter in a SQL query to query a database in the format `Select * from Table where ID in MyList.` Unfortunately, my list is about 800 entries and is getting rejected for being too long. I need an easy way to split it out into multiple queries using smaller lists.

For my Code, I made the list just a few entries and they represent IDs. I have successfully split it, but it runs into a few problems. How can I address these?

1. This seems very inefficient and non-pythonic
2. If requires me to figure out ahead of time as to how many different tuples this needs to be broken out into. If there are 10,000 entries, I can't just break it in half as each part will still be too bug.

My Code:

```
mylist = (12,32,3,45,34,56,45)

mylist1 = []
mylist2 = []
for i in range(0, len(mylist)/2):
    mylist1.append(mylist[i])
for i in range(len(mylist)/2+1, len(mylist)):
    mylist2.append(mylist[i])


print mylist1
print mylist2
```

Comment: You might need to put the IDs in a new table and then do a `JOIN`.

Comment: @WaleedKhan could you expand?

Comment: Have you consider to use divide and conquer algorithm? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while loop would let you consume the list in sizes that you are happy with e.g.

```
data = range(10)

chunk_size = 10

while data:
    sublist, data = data[:chunk_size], data[chunk_size:]

    # Handle subplit
    print sublist
```

Comment: This worked really well! I added my sql to your loop!